# Scilab: Logitfit function of stixbox toolbox

Tags: scilab

Helllo, i've tried to do a logistic regression with the function `logitfit` of the `Scilab` toolbox `stixbox`: i've got an error of size inconsistency. Looking at the function `logitfit.sci`, it seems to me that the calculation of `dff` is not correct. The last two multiplications `.* x'*x` are not size consistent. Also, `dff` should be of size 1xnb to correct the `b` term (below), but i cannot see how such size can be obtained in its calculation.
Thanks to any idea, or reference to this original algorithm of convergence.

Comment: Could you please post the full minimal reproducing example that you run.

Comment: Hello @S.Gougeon, thanks for your interest.  
For example:  

`>y=[0 1 0 0 1 0]' `  
`>x=[1 2 3 4 5 6]'`  
`>logitfit(y,x)   
 !--error 10  Inconsistent multiplication.    
at line      33 of function logitfit called by :  logitfit(y,x)`

Comment: The documentation is very poor, and the code has several errors. `y` must be a column vector of 0 and 1 (OK). `X` must be a square matrix of size `n x n` with `n=length(y)`  (otherwise x * x in the test fails). `fprintf` must be replaced with `mprintf`. Then there is the error you have reported... and maybe other ones afterwards. Apparently, this code comes from a partial translation of some external code.

Comment: Hello Samuel, thanks for your inputs. I'm quite upset that the developpers of the stixbox toolbox could have published it with so many errors...

I've tried to post a ticket on the stixbox forge (forge.scilab.org) but i couldn't manage to create an account...

I cannot see how `x` could be of size `nxn` (also note that the script adds a `one` column to `x`).

best gilles

Comment: The scilab forge is closed. Please post an issue at https://gitlab.com/scilab/forge/stixbox